# "repo init -b branch; repo status" does not show you're on a branch

Tags: git, git-repo

I am struggling to understand `repo` and `git`. I have created a branched `manifest.xml` file that specifies `<default revision="project/master"… />`

Everything works fine but when the `repo sync` is complete there is no indication that each project is on that branch. `git branch` in each project says you aren't on a branch. However if you run `gitk`, you can see that you are at the correct revision.

`repo checkout project/master` says that none of the projects have this branch defined. The output of `git checkout project/master` in a project directory looks like a new branch was created.

If I `git clone project; git checkout project/master`, then everything is as expected.

Questions:

1. What is different about what `repo` is doing?
2. I am trying to define a "new" master branch for our project. Am I really on that branch even though `repo` and `git` do not indicate that?

Please help me to understand so that I can put my mind at ease…

TIA

Answer (score 3):

This is expected. Repo doesn't create a local branch for the remote branch you've listed in the manifest. It's up to you to create a local branch with `repo start` (or the equivalent underlying Git command that `repo start` is just a wrapper of). Repo just checks out the commit that the manifest points to, creating a detached head.

In Git, remote branches can't be checked out for work. All work (i.e. all changes) takes place on local branches. When you ran

```
git clone project
cd project
git checkout project/master
```

the literal meaning of the last command is "check out the branch that matches the project/master pattern, which in the case of a matching remote branch will cause it to be checked out as a detached head", but Git did what it thought you actually meant which is

```
git checkout project/master origin/project/master
```

which creates the local branch project/master based on the origin/project/master remote branch.

Repo's behavior might seem weird, but the intended workflow is that you create topic branches for each little thing you're working on. Repo doesn't know what you're going to work on in a particular git (if at all) so creating branches for you would be presumptuous.

Also, keep in mind that the manifest doesn't necessarily point to branches. The revision attribute could point to tags or even SHA-1s, and creating local branches for them wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

While `repo start <branch_name> --all` must use same branch name on each git repo, it is not suitable for manifest with different `revision` (remote branch).

I found a great solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35617041/6500762) using `repo forall`.

You can use the following flow to make sure each sub git repo is not in headless state and tracking with same branch.

```
repo init <...>
repo sync
repo forall -pc 'git checkout --track $REPO_REMOTE/$REPO_RREV'
```

You can check [repo forall](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo#forall) page for environment variable definition.